May a husband and wife swim together while the wife is niddah
According to Halacha, is it permitted for a husband and wife to swim together while the wife is niddah, or no? Would it be considered harchakot and rabbinically forbidden or no?

There might be several problems with it, but not prohibited per se.
One of the problems is that the husband cannot see body parts that are usually covered when the wife is "niddah".

He may not gaze even at her ankle, nor at any of her covered places (Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh De'ah 195:7).

See also the answer to this question:

May one be in the same swimming pool as his wife (dressed modestly) when she is niddah? Sometimes the husband and wife need to take care of the children within the same pool.

Din.online answers:

The fact that they are in the same swimming pool is not a problem, as long as they are not too close to each other that they can feel each other’s movements. However I understand your question that they are not going swimming together, (something that would be kalus rosh) but they happen to be in the same pool in order to take care of their children.


"they are not going swimming together, (something that would be kalus rosh)" It seems strange to me that the author deems swimming together, that is not in care of children, as automatically being קלות ראש. One can readily conjure up plenty of other swimming scenarios that do not inherently involve קלות ראש (doing laps as part of a health regiment, swimming to escape intense heat, etc.)... not all swimming is horsing around.

@Deuteronomy you mean to believe that their example of taking care of the children is the only scenario where the author of that response would say it is allowed? The response as a whole should be understood that if there is a reason for them to be in the pool at the same time it would not be an issue

@y_g the author is of the opinion that merely being in the pool at the same time (i.e. not swimming) is permitted. He then heavily implies that any swimming together by husband and wife is inherently קלות ראש. I disagree with that characterization and the analysis that emerges therefrom.

@Deuteronomy I just understood the “going swimming” that the author wrote to mean the activity as a whole not the actual act of swimming in the pool at the same time
